# Compiling client-site pug templates into modules

Tags: javascript, pug, parcel

I am serving a web app using Node.js, Express, Parcel and Pug and it all runs very well.

Parcel is bundling up my JS up to a point where I am quite satisfied.

However, I also do some client side templating, and that is only going to increase. I currently compile cs pug template using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43025557/client-side-templating-with-nodejs-and-pug) solution using the pug-cli package (there is also an alternate solution available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52067308/compiling-pug-templates-to-single-client-side-js-file) using pugtalizer); however either solution compiles pug templates into JS with the template function in the global namespace that I can only access when loading the template function via the HTML `<script>` tag.

This results in  me having to load several JS files, which defies the whole attempt to bundle up all JavaScript into one bundle using Parcel.

How can I import (i.e. using ES6 `import()`) the template file in my cs javascript so that it gets bundled?

**UPDATE**

I just analysed the compiled template function. I reformatted it, so as to better analyse what's going on, and added a simple export command to the compiled template file at the end like so:

```
module.exports = { exampleTemplate }
```

I then can import this in my client code and use it as usual:

```
import { exampleTemplate } from '<path>/example'
...
const html = exampleTemplate ({<locals>})
document.getElementByID('target').innerHTML = html
```

All that's left to do is to somehow tell Pug to append that module.exports statement, and we have a solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Pug API supports this functionality out of the box, and `pug-cli` does as well.

All I needed to to in the end is to change my package.json script to:

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "dev:watch:pug": "pug -O '{module: true}' -c -w --name-after-file -o src/client/views src/client/views",
    ...
}
```